# Parsing URL Query String to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, url, query-string

I want to build a function that parses the URL query string (parameters and values) out of the current URL (e.g. document.location) and stores each key value pair (parameter=value) as an individual element within an array.

So for example, if the URL is: 
http://example.com?product=shoes&price=59.99&color=red

Then it returns:
parameters = ["product=shoes","price=59.99",”color=red"];

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you really just want strings like "name=value" in your array? Or do you want actual object values that can be referenced?

Comment: `location.href.split('?')[1].split('&')`

Comment: Just the strings, but i want the array to have a name that can be referenced. Also I want to function to have a name.

Comment: If you're using `location.href` you could use `location.search.slice(1).split('&')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your browser requirements, you can use the `URLSearchParams` object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
```

Or if you need to do it manually, you can split the `location.search` string:

```
var qs = location.search.replace('?', '');  // get querystring and remove question marks
var pairs = qs.split('&');                  // split on ampersand
var items = {};                             // declare object to store key/value pairs

// Loop through pairs and extract the key and the value (and append them to the object)
for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    items[pairs[i].split('=')[0]] = pairs[i].split('=')[1];
}

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.slice()` and `.split()` methods of String:

```js
let str = 'http://example.com?product=shoes&price=59.99&color=red';

let parser = url => url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
               
console.log(parser(str));
```

You can also create an object with key/value pairs by using `.reduce()`:

```js
let str = 'http://example.com?product=shoes&price=59.99&color=red';

let parser = url => url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1)
                       .split('&')
                       .reduce((a, c) => {
                         let [key, value] = c.split('=');
                         a[key] = value;
                         return a;
                       }, {});

console.log(parser(str));
```

**Docs:**

- [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Thanks, this is great. But how do I give a name to the function, and to the array?

Comment: This is problematic for urls with a fragment identifier `#`

Comment: @Evert Yes, you are right but my answer is specific to the format mentioned by OP.